# Java 8 stream and set attribute from call Boolean method

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

Please can you help me resolve this issue I am having when attempting to stream through an array list and call a setter based on a method which returns a Boolean.

Written as a for loop, it would look like this:-

```
for (final PersonDto person : personList) {
    person.setUserCanEdit(userHasWriteRole(person));
}

private Boolean userHasWriteRole(final PersonDto person) {
        return getUserRoles().contains(getReadRole());
    }
```

I have tried a few variations with no success, along the following lines

```
final List<PersonDto> results = personList.stream().filter(a -> a.setUserCanEdit(this::userHasWriteRole)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

... But it complains with
***The target type of this expression must be a functional interface***

Comment: please make clear this `private Boolean userHasWriteRole(final PersonDto person) {
        return getUserRoles().contains(getReadRole());
    }`

Comment: The method isn't really relevant, it has more logic within it, but for the purposes for this issue I wanted to show that it returns a Boolean value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are updating the objects in array list, you can use [forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-)

```
personList.forEach(person ->person.setUserCanEdit(userHasWriteRole(person)));
```

Comment: I tried this but I get "Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to List<PersonDto>"

Comment: `forEach` method is void type @R111

Comment: so how do I accomplish the desired outcome?

Comment: personList will have the desired output, print the list and check it @R111

Comment: Thanks @Deadpool. It looks like that works, but can you tell me why I cant assign the output to a new arraylist?
e.g.List<PersonDto> newList =  personList.forEach(person ->person.setUserCanEdit(userHasWriteRole(person)));

Comment: @R111 Makes a copy of your list and do this operation

Answer (score 1):

I think I would go for:

```
personList.stream()
   .filter(p -> userHasWriteRole(p))
   .forEach(p -> p.setUserCanEdit(true));
```

I think this keeps the intent clear,

Answer (score 0):

The `filter()` method is an intermediate operation of the Stream interface that allows us to filter elements of a stream that match a given Predicate. You can't update data in the filter.
Use `forEach` for this.

```
personList.stream().forEach(a -> a.setUserCanEdit(userHasWriteRole(a)));
```

And if you want to get in new arraylist  make a copy of list and do this operations on new list

```
List<PersonDto> copy = new ArrayList<>(personList);
copy.stream().forEach(a -> a.setUserCanEdit(userHasWriteRole(a)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a list with filtered elements and do the `setUserCanEdit` on every elements in that list; you can do like this:

```java
List<PersonDto> newList = personList.stream()
  .filter(p -> userHasWriteRole(p))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());

newList.forEach(p -> p.setUserCanEdit(true));
```